# Copy Paste not working in onEdit function in Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google App script that needs to return the changes made to the Spreadsheet and return it to slack. The script is failing whenever there is a copy paste done inside the Spreadsheet on the file (Either multiple rows or columns are copied together or a single entry) both are not working.
This is my current script:---

```
**var url ="Slack Webhook URL";
function sendSlackNotification(e) {
var newValue = e.value; 
var oldValue = e.oldValue; 
var user = e.user; 
var row = e.range.getRow();  
var spreadsheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName();
var payload = {
  'text' : user + " just changed from oldValue : '" + oldValue + "' to newValue : '" + newValue  + "' at row : '" + row + "' in the following Sheet : " + spreadsheetName +" :grimacing:"
    };
var params = {
      'method' : 'post',
      'contentType' : 'application/json',
      'payload' : JSON.stringify(payload)
    };
  
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params)
}**
```

Need to fix Copy Paste Functionality while performing onEdit function in Spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

When using onEdit triggers, `value` and `oldValue` only appear on single cells; try adding `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))` in your function and check your execution logs to see what the event object structure looks like.

You will most likely have to modify your function to check whether `range.columnStart`/`range.columnEnd` and `range.rowStart`/`range.rowEnd` are equal to determine if it's a range being edited or a cell and take it from there.